# Show/Hide Table

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have added a nutrition info table to the bottom of my Wordpress/Woocommrece product description.

I am trying to have it hidden and give the customer the option to show the table.

Currently I am able to hide and reveal the information that comes before the table ie - 300g, 10 servings... but the table is always visible.

My code:

```css
.nutrition-read-more-state {
    display: none;
}
.nutrition-read-more-target {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    transition: .25s ease;
}
.nutrition-read-more-state:checked ~ .nutrition-read-more-wrap .nutrition-read-more-target {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: inherit;
    max-height: 999em;
}
.nutrition-read-more-state ~ .nutrition-read-more-trigger:before {
    content: 'Show more';
}
.nutrition-read-more-state:checked ~ .nutrition-read-more-trigger:before {
    content: 'Show less';
} 
.nutrition-read-more-trigger {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    color: #666;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 2;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div><input id="post-2" class="nutrition-read-more-state" type="checkbox" />
<div class="nutrition-read-more-wrap">
<h2>Brand - Product - Product type - Nutrition Information</h2>
<span class="nutrition-read-more-target">
Size: 300g
Serving size: 10g
Servings per container: 30</p>
<table class="tg" style="width: 30%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="tg-yw4l"></th>
<th class="tg-baqh">Per Serving</th>
<th class="tg-baqh">% of RI</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-bd4c" colspan="3">sub-head</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l">
<div style="color: #3b3d3e;">ingredient</div></td>
<td class="tg-baqh">2.5g</td>
<td class="tg-baqh"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-siak">ingredient</td>
<td class="tg-om3m">2g</td>
<td class="tg-om3m"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l">ingredient</td>
<td class="tg-baqh">2g</td>
<td class="tg-baqh"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-siak">ingredient</td>
<td class="tg-om3m">120mg</td>
<td class="tg-om3m">15%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l">ingredient</td>
<td class="tg-baqh">60mg</td>
<td class="tg-baqh">16%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-bd4c" colspan="3">Sub head</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l">ingredient</td>
<td class="tg-baqh"> 500mg</td>
<td class="tg-baqh"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-siak">ingredient</td>
<td class="tg-om3m"> 300mg</td>
<td class="tg-om3m"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l">Caffeine</td>
<td class="tg-baqh"> 200mg</td>
<td class="tg-baqh"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-siak">ingredient</td>
<td class="tg-om3m"> 200mg</td>
<td class="tg-om3m"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-bd4c" colspan="3">ingredient</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-siak">ingredient</td>
<td class="tg-om3m"> 2.2mg</td>
<td class="tg-om3m"> 200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l">ingredient</td>
<td class="tg-baqh"> 2.8mg</td>
<td class="tg-baqh"> 200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-siak">ingredient</td>
<td class="tg-om3m"> 48mg</td>
<td class="tg-om3m"> 300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l">ingredient</td>
<td class="tg-baqh"> 12mg</td>
<td class="tg-baqh"> 200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-le8v" colspan="3">
<div style="color: #3b3d3e;"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: #000000;">Other Ingredients</span></div>
<div style="color: #3b3d3e;"><span style="color: #000000;">Beta-Alanine, Creatine Monohydrate, L-Arginine, Citric Acid (Acidity Regulator), L-Tyrosine, Minerals (Tricalcium Phosphate, Magnesium Carbonate), Extract of Bitter Orange Fruit (Citrus Aurantium), Flavour, Caffeine Raspberry Ketone, Silicone Dioxide (Anti-Caking Agent), Vitamins (Thiamine Mononitrate, Riboflavin, Nicotinic Acid, Calcium Pantothenate, Pyridoxine Hydrochloride, D-Biotin, Folic Acid, Cyanocobalamin), Acesulfame K &amp; Sucralose (Sweeteners), Cochineal &amp; Brilliand Blue (Colourants)</span></div>
<div style="color: #3b3d3e;"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: #000000;"> </span></div>
<div style="color: #3b3d3e;"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: #000000;">Recommended Use</span></div>
<div style="color: #3b3d3e;"><span style="color: #000000;">One serving (10g - 2 teaspoons) dissolved in 200 ml of water Use once a day before training</span></div>
<div style="color: #3b3d3e;"><span style="color: #000000;"> </span></div>
<div style="color: #3b3d3e;"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: #000000;">Warning</span></div>
<div style="color: #3b3d3e;"><span style="color: #000000;">Do not exceed recommended servings for consumption during the day Food supplements should not be used as a substitute for a varied diet Contains caffeine is not recommended for use in children and pregnant women</span></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</span>
</div>
<label class="nutrition-read-more-trigger" for="post-2"></label></div>
```

The snippet works fine here and on code pen but not on my website. any help would be great. I am trying to keep it to CSS only as I find wordpress websites get overloaded with Javascript from plugins which tends to slow it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- CSS can't handle clicks. You have to use JavaScript.
- Follow this
  tutorial for this features:
  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp
- Inputs are for forms, don't use them for UI states.
- Place the script in a script tag or in a file, after the HTML.
- Look at your code in your project and search for JavaScript conflics into the console of Crhome Inspector

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I grace used this technique on another page and it worked fine, the only difference is that I have a table on this page rather than purely text. I don't know if that might be what is making the difference?

Comment: <table> is an HTML Element like div and p and others. Plase the id attribute in your table for make it works with your script.

Comment: Use JavaScript also to change the HTML DOM innerText Property of the button.